# Unzip zip file that end with .exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I using  System.IO.Compression.ZipFile to extract zip file ,**but zip file is ends whith .exe** ,i can do right click and extract if by my self but i need to do this in c#.

Right now i getting this error

```
 zip file end of central directory record could not be found
```

How can i extract this file?

My code

```
string zipPath = DeffDownFolder + @"\archive.exe";
string extractPath = strFilePath + "\\" + AccountNumber;
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Comment: is your zip file looks like this 'archive.zip.exe' if so edit your post

Comment: no, and i try to rename it to 'archive.zip and to archive.zip.exe  then run a code, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If is an .exe is not a .zip. It may be a [self extracting archive zip](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/179), but that dors not make it a zip. You may try with [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/):

> **Does this library read self-extracting zip files?**
>   **Yes**. DotNetZip can read self-extracting archives (SFX) generated by WinZip, and WinZip can read SFX files generated by DotNetZip.

Comment: I all ready tried Ionic.Zip it is do not throw me error,but still don't open the file